# Django Reverse Foreignkey Based on a Field of Second Table

Tags: python, sql, django, foreign-keys

I have the following two tables in Django.

```
class TeamSubscriptions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    soccer_team = models.ForeignKey(SoccerTeam)
    ....
    ....

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'soccer_team_subscriptions'

class MatchSubscriptions(models.Model):
    team_subscriber = models.ForeignKey(TeamSubscriptions, related_name='soccer_user_matches')
    soccer_match = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    winning_team_guess = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    ...
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'soccer_game_subscriptions'
        unique_together = ("team_subscriber", "soccer_match")
```

I want to fetch all subscribers from `Teamsubscriptions`. For all of them, I want to find the corresponding
rows from `MatchSubscriptions` with a specific `soccer_match` ID. The purpose is to get `winning_team_guess` from the second table for some specific `soccer_match` IDs.

Is there any way to do this (Reverse ForeignKey) for a specific `soccer_match` ID..??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with Django's ORM:

```
TeamSubscriptions.objects.filter(matchsubscriptions__soccer_match_id=YOUR_ID)
```

Check out Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) about lookups with relationship.

In general if you want to filter in a queryset you can use the [related query name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) which is by default equal to the [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) of the FK, in your example it's `matchsubscriptions_set`, you only have to remove `_set` as it was generated by Django when you use the queryset.